# Recording frequency of names in the attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, statistics, vba, frequency

I have a question with ArcGIS 9.2. In an attribute table the column [name] includes the name of every place in this layer. Next to that (in columns [numbers]) there should be recorded how often a place of this name is in the map.

How can I calculate this values with VBA in the field calculator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with Field Calculator, but I do know a workaround.

Run [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000.htm) in ArcToolbox with COUNT on the [name] field.  This will create another table where each unique [name] entry will have next to it the number of times it appears in the original layer.  Then [Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000) this table back to your original layer, with the [name] field as the link.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I can just choose between SUM, MEAN, MIN, MAX, RANGE, STD, FIRST and LAST. Is it possible that the COUNT option is not included in ArcGIS 9.2 and just in later varsions?

Comment: You're right, COUNT was not an option in 9.2.  Fortunately, you do have access to the [Frequency](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Frequency_(Analysis)) tool, which basically does the same thing.

Comment: It works really great! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem buddy =)  Be sure to mark this question as "answered" whenever you get a chance.